# Padding with %03.3f doesn't work

Tags: php, lua, printf, string-formatting

I have the following function (in PHP):

```php
function FormatSize( $size ) {
    $size = intval( $size );
    $idx = 0;
    $prefixes = array( "", "Ki", "Mi", "Gi", "Ti", "Pi" );
    while( $size > 1024 ) {
        $size = $size / 1024;
        $idx++;
    }
    return sprintf( "%03.2f %sB", $size, $prefixes[$idx] );
}
```

and the following in lua

```lua
function GetSize( iSize )
    local iSizeTemp, sPrefix, i = tonumber(iSize) or 0, {"", "Ki", "Mi", "Gi", "Ti", "Pi"}, 1
    while iSizeTemp > 1024 do
        iSizeTemp, i = iSizeTemp/1024, i+1
    end
    return string.format( "%03.2f %sB", iSizeTemp, sPrefix[i] )
end
```

The return statement uses `%03.2f` which should return the output as `PQR.XY` format, where `P` or `Q` or both can be zero.

But I'm getting a simple output (the same as `%.2f`) and the padding part (`%03`) seems to have no effect whatsoever. Here is the codepad link ([for PHP](http://codepad.org/olaZY498) and [for Lua](http://codepad.org/4GgjFBnO)) for an example; where I'm passing a number **1285854482** to the function. The output comes to be *`1.20 GiB`* instead of **`001.20 GiB`**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to misundestand the description of `%.f` format specification: this - `%03.2f` - actually means 'allocate *at least* 3 symbols to represent a number, at least 2 of them for representing its non-integer part'. Note that full stop is not included into this `2` - but is included into `3`, so this formatter never actually hits its 'minimum'. )

Change it into `'%06.2f'`, and it'll work as you expect: of 6 symbols, 3 will be spent on a full stop symbol and two digits after, so 3 remain for representing the integer part of the number.

Answer (score 1):

Ah. Found the solution after going through [C++ reference on `printf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/), which states about the number succeeding `%` sign as:

> Minimum number of characters to be printed. If the value to be printed
>   is shorter than this number, the result is padded with blank spaces.
>   The value is not truncated even if the result is larger.